# R fill up matrix without using a loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix, apply, mapply

Hi everybody I'm looking for some coding advice and tricks. I have a 10x10 matrix like this:

```
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
```

and a function that takes two numbers and returns a simple scalar:

```
fct <- function(x1, x2){
return(x1 * x2)
}
```

My function is a bit more complexed but this is just for illustration purpose.

I would like to fill up the matrix mat by applying the function fct to two vectors, let's say:

```
x1 <- c(1:10)
x2 <- c(1:10)
```

I can easily do it with a loop but I was wondering if someone knew a better way, maybe using mapply/Map.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Like so `outer(x1, x2)` ? You would need to pass your function to the `FUN` argument of `outer`, default is `"*"`.

Comment: Efficiency will depend very much on whether or not your function is vectorized....

Comment: Thanks @markus and Gregor. I just vectorized my function and used outer that I didn't know before. It worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorizing the function like so:

```
fct <- function(x1, x2){
out <- numeric(length = length(x1))
for(i in seq_along(x1)) {
    out[i] <- x1[i] * x2[i]
 }
return(out)
}
```

Then applying outer:

```
outer(x1, x2, fct)
```

will do the trick!

Thank you!

Comment: If what you presented above is what your function really is supposed to do then you should use `outer(x1, x2)` This will be much much more efficient then your non-vectorized solution: `library(microbenchmark); x1 <- c(1:1000); x2 <- c(1:1000); microbenchmark(OP = outer(x1, x2, fct), outer = outer(x1, x2), times = 20)`

Comment: @markus the function I created is a bit more complexed, returning a number according to a set of conditions. It worked fine for me with what I was trying to do. But I only used small vectors so you're probably right about the efficiency. Thanks a lot for your input!